# How do I set simple linear constraints with dual_annealing?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I can set simple bounds to use with dual_annealing: E.g.

```
upper_bound = 20
num_points = 30
bounds = [(0, upper_bound) for i in range(num_points)]
res = dual_annealing(fun, bounds, maxiter=1000)
```

But I would also like to constrain the variables so that `x_i >= x_{i-1}+0.5` for each i. That is each variable should be at least 0.5 larger than the one preceding it.

How can you do that?

If scipy can't do it, are there other libraries with global optimizers that can?

Comment: PuLP, Gurobi, and CPLEX

Comment: @MykolaZotko I am looking for an open source answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this right, so if something is wrong, please correct me.

### Problem

From you bounds specification I understand that `fun` is a function of 30 variables `{x_1, x_2, ...,x_i-1, x_i, x_i+1, ..., x_30}`. What you want is to enforce that these variables obey relationship `x_i >= x_i-1+0.5`. This can indeed be achieved with Lagrange multipliers as stated by the other answer, but sometimes the equations are just too complex.

This is a very basic brute-force alternatice - a constrained numerical optimization:

```py
from scipy.optimize import dual_annealing
import numpy as np

# an example objective function
def fun(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return np.sum(x)

# let's create a simple wrapper using a callable class that will
# 'watch' that constrains are fulfilled.
# hit and miss attributes are only for convenience
# to see some stats at the end
class Wrapper:

    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        self.hit = 0
        self.miss = 0

    def __call__(self, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        # check if all differences are higher than 0.5
        # if yes than return the value of objective function
        if np.all(np.diff(x) > 0.5):
            self.hit += 1
            return self.fun(x)
        # if the constraints are not met than return inf. This effectively
        # discourages the optimizer from visiting the points of function where
        # the constrains are not fulfilled
        else:
            self.miss += 1
            return np.inf        

upper_bound = 20
num_points = 30
bounds = [(0, upper_bound) for i in range(num_points)]

wrapped = Wrapper(fun)

# We specify x0 starting point as the optimizer might fail to start otherwise.
# This is because your constraints are quite limiting and it might be hard to
# generate initial state. The optimizer makes 1000 attempts to do so and than
# fails. This avoids that
res = dual_annealing(
    wrapped,
    bounds,
    maxiter=1000,
    x0=np.linspace(0, upper_bound, 30)
)
print(res.x)
print(wrapped.hit, wrapped.miss)
```

### Notes

There are a few drawbacks here to watch for:

- I do not know how computationally intensive `fun` is but with such tight constraints this can get resource intensive, even prohibitive pretty fast in 30D space. If you run this you will see that hit/miss ratio is approximately 5/8
- Due to the computational intensity you might have problem to converge
- You should also consider how hard the constraints are. Maybe they can be relaxed a bit and `np.inf` can be substituted by exponential of polynomial function. This would be better as it would not introduce any discontinuities that are there now, although simulated annealing should be OK with them.
- Due to use of 'np.inf' and discontinuities it introduces it might be necessary to switch off local search with `dual_annealing(..., no_local_search=True)` as it uses BFGS and you may encounter exploding gradients there.
- If your function is simple enough you should attempt to do this on paper with Lagrange multipliers, this will always be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Lagrangian multiplier to penalize the objective function if your constraints aren't satisfied. Alternatively you can use the `differential_evolution` minimiser.

Comment: Could you show how to use a Lagrange multiplier to penalize the objective function please.

Comment: It's effectively a penalty term that you add on the objective that gets worse the more the constraints are exceeded. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier.